# Multiple values on HTTP headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, http-headers

Is this correct?

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json, application/pdf')
```

I want to accept both json and pdf files.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, [it is correct](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html). Example form w3c:

```
Accept: text/plain, text/html
```

Answer (score 2):

More generally, multiple value headers must be expressable as a comma-separated list, so expressing the values this way is valid. Also valid would be to include multiple `Accept` headers, which the server might optionally compress back into a comma-separated list.

From an HTTP RFC: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html

> Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]. It MUST be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each separated by a comma. The order in which header fields with the same field-name are received is therefore significant to the interpretation of the combined field value, and thus a proxy MUST NOT change the order of these field values when a message is forwarded.